# Accounting for non-independence of measurements in analysis of variance

Tags: anova, predictor, independence, friedman-test

I have 10 measurements for each of 50 patients, each obtained at 3 different time points (i.e. 500 + 500 + 500 values). The measurements are of the same quantity but were measured in different locations (signal intensity in MRI scans).

If I assume that there is independence between the 10 measurements per patient, I can simply use a repeated measures ANOVA or a Friedman's test. However, how can I adjust for the non-independence of measurements on a per-patient basis? Given that the patient number is a non-ordinal variable, can this be used as a covariate and how?

Comment: I don't understand your comment *If I assume that there is independence between the 10 measurements per patient, I can simply use a repeated measures ANOVA *. Repeated measurements models are used to model dependence, so why can you not use them? Please add more context!

Comment: Thanks for the reply kjetil. Basically, if I plot the 500 measurements at, say, the first time point I can get 50 distinct clusters of 10 measurements each because they may be heavily dependent. Wouldn't this be some violation of ANOVA assumptions, or I can still use it without accounting for it as a covariate?